# Application of Gronwall Inequality

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, banach-spaces

Let  $T>0$ and $f\in C(\mathbb R, L^{2}(\mathbb R))$ with the following property:

Put $g(t):= \sup\limits_{0\leq \tau\leq t} \|f(\tau)\|_{X},$   where $X \subset L^{2}$ and $X$ is  a Banach Space.

For $0\leq t \leq T, $ $0<p<\infty,$
 $g(t)^p \leq  1+ \int_{0}^{t} g(\tau)^{p} d\tau.$

> My Question is: Can we expect to show that $g\in L^{\infty}([0, T])$?

**My  Vague Idea:** I think, we need to use [Gronwall Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) for the integral form, but I am little confuse which form I should consider, and how  to apply.

Comment: Well, simply the fact that $g(t)^p\leqslant C$ for every $t$ in $[0,T]$, with $C=1+\int_0^Tg(\tau)^pd\tau$, allows to conclude, no?

Comment: @Did: Why  $C< \infty$?

Comment: Depends on your hypotheses, that $g(T)$ is finite suffices (anyway, Gronwall does not seem needed). In the other direction, note that $g(0)=0$, $g(\tau)=+\infty$ for every $\tau>0$ does solve the integral inequality...

Comment: @Did: Thanks: But to apply Gronwall do we need continuity assumption on the hypothesis? That is my confusion.

Comment: The answer to *that* is at [the obvious place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality#Integral_form_with_locally_finite_measures).

Comment: @Inquisitive: I have abandoned my previous post. I don't think that I read the question carefully enough.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro; Any way that answered has help me to understand something. Would  please see this [question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/234539/how-to-use-grownwall-inequality)?  Essentially I was asking this. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that the paper lacks justification in the application of Gronwall's lemma. What has been proved there is the implication $$\omega \in L^{\alpha'}_{\rm loc}([0, \infty))\ \Rightarrow \omega \in L^\infty_{\rm loc}([0, \infty)).$$ So either the paper is wrong or (more probably) the $L^{\alpha'}$ integrability of $\omega$ is obvious.